# Android app to easily deny Internet access to apps, does not show apps that don't use it in the first place

Tags: android, open-source, networking, internet, firewall

To prevent a particular app from using the Internet, [NetGuard](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=eu.faircode.netguard)/[AFWall+](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall)/[XPrivacy](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy) can be used.

**PROBLEM**: They shows all apps on the phone, even the apps whose source code does not even attempt to access the Internet anyway.

Is there another app to allow/disallow Internet access, that only shows apps that potentially will try (or have tried) to access the Internet?

Requirements:

- Free & Open source
- Show only apps that use the Internet
- Easier than a full-featured firewall

May require root.

The implementation could look at the Android manifest permissions (especially if the app also targets Android 5), or reverse-engineer the APK looking for network-related Android API calls, or in the worst case keep a log of apps that have used the Internet recently.

Comment: Solutions requiring root are accepted? Must be free or can be paid (in the latter case, what price limit – and yes, some Open-Source apps have a price tag for the *compiled* APK)? Related question on our Android sister-site has some solutions as well: [In Android 6, how to deny an app permission to access the network?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/138311/16575)

Comment: @Izzy: Updated, thanks! Yes I came from that question actually. The open source options there list all apps.

Comment: Thanks! As you name *Xprivacy* – have you tried checking there "by permission"? IIRC that included only those apps requiring those, but I might remember wrongly.